# Table View not updating when new array item added

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to get a simple example of Table view working. Each row is of Class TableRow:

```
    import Foundation

    class TableRow: NSObject{
    var rowNumber: Int = 1
    var value: Double  = 100.0
    init(_ rowNumber: Int, _ value: Double){
        self.rowNumber = rowNumber
        self.value = value
        super.init()
    }
   }
```

I created this TableWindowController class with an associated TableWindowController.xib which has the table view in it:

```
import Cocoa

class TableWindowController: NSWindowController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    //not sure I need @IBOutlet here - just trying it
    @IBOutlet var rows: [TableRow] = [TableRow.init(1,12.2)]

    override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name?{
        return NSNib.Name.init("TableWindowController")
    }

    @IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any?){
        rows.append(TableRow.init(23, 245.3))
        print("Row count now = \(rows.count)")
        let cvc = self.contentViewController
        //checking if contentViewController is non nil as thought of trying to refresh it's view
        print("content view controller: \(String(describing: cvc))")
    }

    //NSTableViewDataSource implementation
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return rows.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        let r = rows[row]
        switch tableColumn!.title{
        case "Row": return r.rowNumber
        case "Value": return r.value
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I’ve set the Table View outlets for dataSource and delegate to Files Owner (i.e. TableWindowController). I’ve added an “Add” button and connected it’s Sent Actions Action to File’s Owner addRow.
[Table View Outlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT5yO.jpg)
[Add button Sent Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcAk2.jpg)

I do the following set up in AppDelegate:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var tableWindowController: TableWindowController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let twc = TableWindowController()
        twc.showWindow(self)
        tableWindowController = twc

        //insert some data
        let rows: [TableRow] = [    TableRow(1, 1.23),TableRow(2, 235.5),TableRow(234, 25.42),
                                    TableRow(27, 16247.32),TableRow(23,243.1),TableRow(15,249.3),
                                    TableRow(26,424.234)]
        tableWindowController?.rows = rows // set the data for the table
        tableWindowController?.rows.append(TableRow(17,236.2)) //test appending adds an item
        tableWindowController?.addRow(nil) // test that addRow adds an item

    }
}
```

When I run this I get my table populated with the initial set up data plus the row I .append above and the row from .addRow(nil). When I click my “Add” button the addRow method is called as I see in the console the row count increasing:

```
Row count now = 9
content view controller: nil
Row count now = 10
content view controller: nil
Row count now = 11
content view controller: nil
```

The table view does not show the new values. I tried:

```
self.contentViewController?.view.needsDisplay = true
```

Which didn’t work as contentViewController is nil.

I’m pulling my hair out as I assume this is very simple for someone with experience of Cocoa and SWIFT. I tried using an Array Controller but that seemed more confusing and felt my understanding would be better if I wired it up like this first.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's doesn't appear to have .reloadData. This is SWIFT 4 - I've been noticing a lot of things I find online are different when using SWIFT 4

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

Comment: thanks - that set me on the right path. I needed to be able to access the TableView. Till now I hadn't worked out how to get an @IBOutlet for the TableView. Not quite sure how I managed it this time but connected the TableView in to . my TableViewController so I could call reloadData() on it

Comment: `UITableView` or `NSTableView`?

Comment: NSTableView. I had to call reloadData() - the bit I hadn't figured out was how to get hold of the NSTableView. Then figure out how to create the @IBOutlet in interface build. V new to this game.

Comment: You don't have to reload all rows, insert a row in the table view or reload the new row.